# Whether the equality $C^{m}_{2m}=\Sigma_{i=1}^{m}C^{i}_{m+1}C^{i-1}_{m-1}$ holds or not?

Tags: combinatorics

I've tried some values of $m$, and found that the equality $C^{m}_{2m}=\Sigma_{i=1}^{m}C^{i}_{m+1}C^{i-1}_{m-1}$ holds. But I can't give it a proof. Can anybody give some suggestions?

Comment: Since $\binom{m-1}{k-1}=\binom{m-1}{m-k}$, we can rewrite the proposed identity as $$\binom{2m}m=\sum_{k=1}^m\binom{m+1}k\binom{m-1}{m-k}=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m+1}k \binom{m-1}{m-k}\;;$$ this is a special case of [Vandermonde’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity), which can be proved in a variety of ways, some of which can be found at the link and on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Compare the coefficients of $x^m$ in   $$(1+x)^{2m}=(1+x)^{m-1}(x+1)^{m+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious graphical picture of VanderMonde equality. Imagine a 2m set split between an $m+1$--set A and an $m-1$--set B. An $m$--set E is then split itself into $E \cap A$ of size $i$ and $E \cap B$ of size $m-i$. Summing over $i$ the result follows. Note that ${m-1 \choose m-i}={m-1 \choose i-1}.$